# Writing a script to copy two files from each directory to each of their corresponding directories

Tags: bash, shell

I have 19 directories (0, n10, n20, n30, ... n180) under the folder "mini". I need to copy two files from each directory (0_mini_vh1.coor and 0_mini_vh1.xsc, n10_mini_vh1.coor and n10_mini_vh1.xsc, so on) into their corresponding directories with the same name (0, n10, n20, so on) under the folder "production". So far, I have this written for a script, but it doesn't seem to be working. How should I improve the script?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for f in n10  n100  n110  n120  n130  n140  n150  n160  n170  n180  n20  n30  n40  n50  n60  n70  n80  n90
do
cd $f
echo "cp $f_mini_vh1.coor ../../production/$f"
echo "cp $f_mini_vh1.xsc ../../production/$f"
cd ../
done
```

Comment: if the target directory is always before the first `_`, you can retrieve its name via `f=n10_mini_vh1.coor; echo ${f%%_*}`

Answer (score 1):

```
for f in n{10..180..10}; do (
    cd "$f"
    echo cp "$f"_mini_vh1.{coor,xsc} ../../production/"$f"
) done
```

You can use curly braces to expand to all of the desired names: `{start..stop..incr}`. You can use the same trick to combine the two file names with `{coor,xsc}`.

Be careful writing `$f_mini_vh1`. That's a variable called `f_mini_vh1`. To separate `f` from the rest you need to write either `${f}_mini_vh1` or `"$f"_mini_vh1`. I recommend the latter to accord with general guidance that one always quote variable expansions.

A subshell with parentheses will save you from having to `cd ../` each time. I like to use a subshell any time I use `cd` in a script to limit the scope of the directory change.

You could also just skip the `cd`-ing entirely by passing adding `$f` to the `cp` command:

```
for f in n{10..180..10}; do
    echo cp "$f"/"$f"_mini_vh1.{coor,xsc} ../production/"$f"
done
```

Comment: I ran the script you listed first, but it came up with these errors:                         ./copy.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `vh1.{coor,'
./copy.sh: line 4: ` echo cp "$f"_mini)vh1.{coor, xsc} ../../production/"$f"'

Comment: Don't put a space after the comma.

Answer (score 0):

This could also be done with an array and a while loop!

This is the way I would do it:

```
arr=(0 n10  n100  n110  n120  n130  n140  n150  n160  n170  n180  n20  n30  n40  n50  n60  n70  n80  n90)
cnt=0
while [ $cnt -lt ${#arr[@]} ]; do
f=${arr[$cnt]}
cp ./$f/${f}_mini_vh1.xsc ../production/$f
cp ./$f/${f}_mini_vh1.coor ../production/$f
let cnt=cnt+1
done
```

But I'm still relatively new and always learning and John's method seems cleaner, but I wanted to offer an alternative :) This should work too.